# How to show german characters in csv file via fputcsv function

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to show a MySQL row from the database which contains German characters but it shows me the output like below in the CSV file all the English characters works fine I don't know where I am going wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

```
Output: Ã–/Ã¶Ã–/Ã¶Ã–/Ã¶ Ã–/Ã¶Ã–/Ã¶Ã–/Ã¶Ã–/Ã¶    Ã–/Ã¶Ã–/Ã¶  Ã–/Ã¶Ã–/Ã¶Ã–/Ã¶ Ã–/Ã¶Ã–/Ã¶Ã–/Ã¶ Ã–/Ã¶Ã–/Ã 

Input: Ö/öÖ/öÖ/ö    Ö/öÖ/ö  Ö/öÖ/öÖ/ö   Ö/öÖ/öÖ/öÖ/ö    Ö/öÖ/öÖ/ö   Ö/öÖ/ö  


$sql = "SELECT forename,surname,company,address,phone,email FROM `user_data`";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $fp = fopen('php://output','w');
    $fields=array("forename","surname","company","address","phone","email");
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    while ($list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    fputcsv($fp, $list);
    }
    header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to make sure that the encoding of your database column/table has the correct charset:
`SHOW CREATE TABLE Tablename;`

Second: When you're inserting data into the table you have to make sure that the encoding you're using is utf8 also.